# Adding a Ghost blog on a Firebase subdirectory

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, ghost-blog

I have a webapp hosted on Firebase Hosting. My domain is connected to this.

I have a Ghost blog hosted on Google Cloud Platform (VM - Compute Engine). I'd like for this to be routed to example.com/blog. I understand that I have to use rewrites (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites).

My questions are:

1. Is just using rewrites enough, or do I need to use reverse proxy requests? If so, can this be done on Firebase?
2. The VM currently just has a static IP (and therefore no SSL certification). Can I use this static IP, or do I need to connect it to an HTTPS domain in order for example.com/blog to be SSL certified?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Firebase Hosting only allows you to do rewrites for files on hosting or Functions in the same project.